# Making Updates in Database in ActiveAdmin after clicking a button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am new to ActiveAdmin and Ruby on Rails. I have resource name Reservation. So reservations.rb file I have created button using following code

```
div class: "button" do
 button_to "Decline", :class => "btn" 
end
```

Now after clicking this button I just want to change the value of reservation.status to "Declined" in database for that reservation.

I have added following code. But it doesn't change the value in database.

```
action_item :approved, only: :show do
    link_to 'Approved', '#'
    reservation.status="Approved"
end
```

Comment: Use an [action item](https://activeadmin.info/8-custom-actions.html#action-items)

Comment: So how do I change the value of my reservation.status="Approved" using action item. I have added the following block, but it doesnt change the value in database.                                                                                                            action_item :approved, only: :show do
  link_to 'Approved', '#'
  reservation.status="Approved"
 end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a member action paired with an action item.  The action item displays the button and the member action performs the action, so:

```
action_item :approve, only: :show do
  a 'Approve', href: approve_reservation_path(reservation)
end

member_action :approve do
  reservation.update_attributes!(status: 'Approved')
end
```

I admit the documentation could be better and the demo does not include an example, PRs welcome. `link_to` instead             of `a` is fine. Specifying `patch` as the method would be more correct but not strictly necessary.